# openmp parallel program is much slower than serial

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, reduction

```
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <omp.h>
# define KE 1000
# define NSTEPS 100000

main()
{
    float ex[KE],hy[KE];
    float bn[NSTEPS];
    int n,k,kc,ke;
    float ddx,dt,T;
    float t0,spread,pulse;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    kc = KE/2;
    t0 = 40.0;
    spread = 12;
    T = 0;
    FILE * temp = fopen("Exserial.txt", "w");
    for (k=0; k <= KE; k++ ) {
        ex[k] = 0.0;
        hy[k] = 0.0;
    }
    for (n=1; n<=NSTEPS ; n++) {
        T = T + 1;
        pulse = exp(-.5*(pow( (t0-T)/spread,2.0) ));
        ex[kc] = pulse;
#pragma omp for 
        for (k=1; k <=KE; k++) { 
#pragma omp atomic update
            ex[k] = ex[k] + .5*( hy[k-1] - hy[k] ) ;
        }
#pragma omp for
        for (k=0; k <=KE-1; k++) {
#pragma omp atomic update
            hy[k] = hy[k] + .5*( ex[k] - ex[k+1] ) ;
        }
    }
    for (k=1; k <=KE; k++) { 
        fprintf(temp, "%f\n",ex[k]);
        printf("%f\n",ex[k]);
    }
}
```

```
SERIAL RUN
real    0m1.210s
user    0m1.212s
sys 0m0.000s
PARALLEL RUN
real    0m3.194s
user    0m3.188s
sys 0m0.004s
```

This parallel program takes more time then the sequential run.

How can I improve the parallel performance?

Comment: You have NO parallel section in your code. So it is purely sequential. (`#pragma omp for` do not parallelizes, while `#pragma omp parallel for` does), And you pay the price of the (useless in a serial context) atomic access.  This is done by special very expensive atomic instructions Both issues probably explain your problems.

Comment: Why are you using atomic update there anyways?

Comment: And a stack allocated array of 100000 floats is probably not a smart thing.

Comment: Oh, and all your loops go out of bounds on the arrays.

Comment: I'm still not getting any time advantage by removing atomic update. I'm getting probably same time for both serial and parallel execution.

Comment: Inner loops are to update ex and hy for NSTEPS itteration

Comment: It's actually quite tricky to correctly interpret the output of `time` when executing parallel programs.  Better to use `omp_wtime`.  There is a myriad questions and answers here on SO on this and related topics.  Oh, and don't use `clock` either.